# UILocalNotification is not firing every 3 seconds

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I want to let user choose between 2 types of notifications. One of them is 10 different local notifications which are fired during the day with a period of 1 hour between each of them and it works quite well.
The second option is firing notifications all at once (I mean all ten notifications with a period between each of them 3 sec). 
Here is my method scheduling notification:

```
-(void)scheduleForToday
{
  for (UILocalNotification *notif in [[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications])
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication]cancelLocalNotification:notif];

 for (NSString *string in self.words){
                  NSDateComponents *currentComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    [currentComponents setHour:hour];
    [currentComponents setMinute:minute];
    currentComponents.second = 0;

                  UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
                  notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
                  currentComponents.second = [self.words indexOfObject:string]*3;
                  notif.fireDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:currentComponents];
                  notif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",word];
                  notif.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"key", nil);
                  notif.userInfo = userDict;
                  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
}
```

}

After method was executed, I put

`NSLog(@"Finished Setiing Today Notifications %@",[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]);`

And I am getting correct schedule of notifications, but neither on device, nor on simulator they are not shown, when my app is in background. What could be an issue? Any advice is appreciated.
[image: Notification Schedule]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can get rid of the initial loop for canceling the notifications and use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

Then, instead of using a for-in statement, just use a regular for statement so you can keep track of the index.

```
for (int i = 0; i < self.words.count; i ++) {

}
```

Then, for fire date, you should try using NSDate's `dateByAddingTimeInterval:` and pass it the index+1 multiplied by the amount of time you want in between the notifications. The way you were doing it before was more or less scheduling all the notifications to fire within milliseconds of eachother.

```
notif.fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:(i + 1) * 3];
```

Comment: still no effect, even if i increase time interval up to 15 sec. :(

Answer (score -3):

set repeatInterval for NSLocal notification

```
 notif.repeatInterval=3*NSSecondCalendarUnit;
```

Comment: each notification has different body, so I do not need to repeat it, I need to show different notif after 3 sec

Comment: you can use nstimer and set time interval 3 second

Comment: NSTimer *timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(after:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

Comment: -(void)after:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    
}

Comment: [`repeatInterval`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009565-CH1-SW3) is a property of type `NSCalendarUnit` and required a `NSCalendarUnit` type. Not a time interval, you can just assign one type of `NSCalendarUnit`

Comment: You cannot multiply NSCalendarUnit. As @rckoenes mentioned you can only assign direct value.